# Specific Excel function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016

I need to format some data in excel and I don't know how to write a very specific function and even worse, I don't know how to google it. The code in C-like programming language would be as the following:

```
if(x>1000)
   x = x/100+x%100;
else
   x = x;
```

I know the format of Excel formula, but something like this, certainly doesn't work:

```
=IF(A2>1000,A2/100+A2%100,A2)
```

Any help regarding this problem would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use %.

Use MOD function instead.

How to:
https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-mod-function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. Here is the excel formula.

```
=IF(A2>1000,INT(A2/100)+((A2/100)-INT(A2/100))*100,A2)
```